# BeautifulSoup Loop Not Locating All hrefs

Tags: python, loops, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, href

I am trying to use both requests and BeautifulSoup libraries to scrape hrefs from the following page so I can loop through them and extract product data from those pages. My program, however, is only successful at extracting 160 of 286.

https://www.homedepot.ca/en/home/categories/outdoors/sheds-and-outdoor-structures/gazebos-pergolas-and-solariums.html

I have read some related posts that suggest changing between html.parser, lxml and html5lib can help solve this, but not in my case. I have tried each of them and none of them produce a significantly improved performance.

Here is my code. Can anybody identify why it is unable to produce all of the hrefs? Is it possibly some JavaScript that I am not handling? Or possibly broken html?

```
import re
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 

productlinks = []
session = requests.Session()

for x in range(1,9):
    url = (f'https://www.homedepot.ca/en/home/categories/outdoors/sheds-and-outdoor-structures/gazebos-pergolas-and-solariums.html?page={x}')
    r = session.get(url, params={'url': url, 'wait': 5}, headers=headers, verify=False)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')
    grid = soup.find('acl-product-card-group')
    productlist = grid.find_all('article')
    for item in productlist:
           get_urls = 'https://www.homedepot.ca/'+ item.find('a', href=True).get('href')
           productlinks.append(get_urls)
print(len(productlinks))
```

Comment: That URL currently returns 403 "access denied". Not sure if the site is geo-fenced or whether it's just broken for everyone. Does the link still work for you?

Comment: `requests` doesn't handle javascript at all.  If the page dynamically generates the page content with javascript, requests will never see it.

Comment: Hey Jack Taylor, yes the link does still work for me. Not sure if geo-fencing would have an impact since these are predominately all online products only.

Answer (score 0):

a direct call to the hidden `API` below:

```py
import requests
from urllib.parse import urljoin



def main(url):
    params = {
        'category': 'l3-gazebospergolassolariums17',
        'a;page': 1,
        'a;pageSize': 40,
        'apiCall': 'true',
        'a;lang': 'en'
    }
    r = requests.get(url, params=params)
    for item in r.json()['products']:
        print(urljoin(url, item['url']))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main('https://www.homedepot.ca/api/search/v1/search')
```

Comment: Hello Ahmed, I appreciate the help! I threw the above function into my program, but it did not improve the performance. What is this trying to accomplish?

Comment: @mahoneym what happens when you run the code sorry?

Comment: I get the same result as before: 160 hrefs out of 286.

Comment: loop over pages `'a;page': 1,`

Comment: Hey Ahmend, sorry I am more of a python novice and might need your help understanding how I need to incorporate this function into the code. Below is what I have so far. Any advice?

Answer (score 0):

Ahmed,

Here is my code

for x in range(1,9):

```
def main(url):
    params = {
        'category': 'l3-gazebospergolassolariums17',
        'a;page': x,
        'a;pageSize': 40,
        'apiCall': 'true',
        'a;lang': 'en'
    }
r = requests.get(url, params=params)
for item in r.json()['products']:
    print(urljoin(url, item['url']))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main('https://www.homedepot.ca/api/search/v1/search')

url = (f'https://www.homedepot.ca/en/home/categories/outdoors/sheds-and-outdoor-structures/gazebos-pergolas-and-solariums.html?page={x}')
r = session.get(url, params=params, headers=headers, verify=False)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')
grid = soup.find('acl-product-card-group')
productlist = grid.find_all('article')
for item in productlist:
       get_urls = 'https://www.homedepot.ca/'+ item.find('a', href=True).get('href')
       get_prices = re.sub("[^0-9]", "", item.find('div', class_='acl-product-card__price-dollars').text.strip())
       productlinks.append(get_urls)
       productprices.append(get_prices)
```

print(len(productlinks))